# A function to replace an element in a string with another element

Tags: c++, string

I want to replace all of the Uppercase letters in string with lowercase letters is there any function to do so because the replace function is not giving any result.
Here is my code..

```
    for (int i = 0 ; i < string. size() ; i++ )
    {
        if (string[i] >= 65 && string[i] <= 90)
        {
            string.replace(string[i] , 1 ,string[i]+32);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is `string` here? Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Note that the 1st argument of [`std::string::replace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/replace) should be the index, not the character.

Comment: see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/locale/tolower/

Comment: Are you looking for http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/tolower/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should read the documentation for [`replace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/replace) - first argument is position of the substring to replace, not the character you want to replace.

So, `string.replace(i , 1 ,string[i]+32);` should work.
Personally, I would go with

```
for(auto& p : string) p=std::tolower(p);
```

Comment: You forgot to assign the tolower result.

Comment: @DanM. Ups, nice catch.

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to use transform

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <locale>

int main()
{
  std::transform(string.begin(), string.end(), string.begin(), ::tolower);
}
```